# How can i access a database hosted on bluehost/godaddy/hostinger from xampp installation

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I have a PHP website used for research purposes and users from 6 countries. This site needs to CRON data from different websites and store to database. currently I have hosted it on GoDaddy. right now when I try to CRON, its gives me 503 error. Can I CRON from my local installation of XAMPP and save those data to database hosted on GoDaddy or any other hosting provider? can someone help me on this by telling what I should do?

Comment: What do you mean call cron? Cron runs in the back round. This sound like you need to be taking to your providor.

Comment: read this to connect database https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-a-mysql-database-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16103

Comment: thanks @lexaVey. Thats what exactly i was looking

Comment: As @LexaVey points out, and having had dealing with Godaddy in the distant past, they usually provide their own fail-safe script in their knowledge base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow documentation here https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-a-mysql-database-in-my-linux-hosting-account-16103